# MongoDB mongoose, insert value in array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection "MyCollection" like this

```
_id: ObjectId('asdasdasd')
myArray: Array
  0: Object
     _id: ObjectId('asdadas')
     name: "My object A"
     description: "My description A"
  1: Object
     _id: ObjectId('bsdadas')
     name: "My object B"
```

`name` and `description` are present in the model.

How could I insert a `"description"` in the 1: Object?

I know how can overwrite the entire array, or how to add a property in an object, example:

```
await MyCollection.updateMany(
  {name: 'some filter, but in my example I only have 1 document'},
  {
    'someObject.someNewOptions.myNewOption': 'example of new value'
  }
);
```

But how do something like that in an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.collection.update({
  "myArray._id": "bsdadas"
},
{
  "$set": {
    "myArray.$.description": "My description B"
  }
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/el32otp7Nwv)